# List displaying only last record using jstl in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the all record form servlet and loop it in the jsp 
but I just get the last record

```
String[] SchoolName = request.getParameterValues("shoolname");
         String[] DateFrom = request.getParameterValues("Dateform");
         String[] DateTo = request.getParameterValues("Datato");
         String[] DiscriptDetails = request.getParameterValues("Dscript");

         for ( int i = 0 ; i < SchoolName.length;i++ ) {
            educatiodetails edu = new educatiodetails();
            edu.setSchoolName(SchoolName[i]);
            edu.setDateFrom(DateFrom[i]);
            edu.setDateTo(DateTo[i]);
            edu.setDiscriptDetails(DiscriptDetails[i]);

                     EducatiIMP education = new EducatiIMP();
                     education.addEducation(edu);
                     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

                         addEducation.getList();
                         EducatiIMP ado = new EducatiIMP();

                         educatiodetails educat = ado.geteducatiodetails(SchoolName[i]);
                         session.setAttribute("educat",educat);
                         }
```

and this is my jsp code for the foreach loop and i just get
the last record form my database can any one help???????!!!!!

```
           <c:forEach items="${educat.schoolName}" var="item" varStatus="state">

            <h2><c:out value="${item}"/></h2>

           </c:forEach>

can anyone please help me.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If *${educat.schoolName}* is array of course, you could try this:

```
...
<c:forEach items="${educat.schoolName}" var="item" varStatus="state">

 <c:out value="${educat.schoolName[state.index]}"/>

</c:forEach>
...
```

Comment: I got this message The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property '0'.

Comment: What type of educat.schoolName? It must be array or List/Set in this case. 
Can you share your code of EducationDetails class?